# datetime : ValueError: day is out of range for month

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, python-datetime, valueerror

The script I'm writing takes two dates and gives back the duration between them, it uses the `datetime` built-in module.

```
import datetime
print('Enter the dates [DD/MM/YYYY]!')

date1 = input('Date 1: ')
date2 = input('Date 2: ')

year1 = int(date1[6:])
month1 = int(date1[3:5])
day1 = int(date1[:2])

year2 = int(date2[6:])
month2 = int(date2[3:5])
day2 = int(date2[:2])

date1 = datetime.date(day1, month1, year1)
date2 = datetime.date(day2, month2, year2)

print(date1 - date2)
```

It keeps showing me

> ValueError: day is out of range for month.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're providing the `date` constructor's arguments in the wrong order. `date` takes the arguments, `year`, `month`, `day`, i.e.:

```py
date1 = datetime.date(year1, month1, day1)
date2 = datetime.date(year2, month2, day2)
```